# Xcode Simulator Crash with Rosetta error after Ventura update

Tags: xcode, apple-m1, apple-silicon, macos-ventura, rosetta

Upgraded to MacOS Ventura and since then, the tvOS Simulator always crashes just after launching with the following message:

```
rosetta error: unable to get state for thread the runtime suspended
```

> Processor : M1

> Xcode Version : 14.0 & 14.1(Both displays same error)

Detailed Error Report is as follows:

```
Incident Identifier: C6F292AE-17D3-4DCA-9F5A-E3159044E994
CrashReporter Key:   C2CA0298-286B-1698-1DF3-EBF4DDE98FEE
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro18,1
Process:             **** [78553]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D4D254F8-517E-4466-9245-******/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/************
Identifier:          com.***.***.***
Version:             1.0.0 (1)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [78465]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.D4D254F8-517E-4466-9245-61B515B5E11C [10286]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [5643]

Date/Time:           2022-11-03 17:52:57.5440 +0530
Launch Time:         2022-11-03 17:51:56.6992 +0530
OS Version:          macOS 13.0 (22A380)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00007ff7ffd4a9a0
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler [78553]
```

```
Triggered by Thread:  2

Thread 0::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd4f6b8 ???
1   ???                                    0x10583a874 ???
2   libsystem_platform.dylib               0x114848c33 _sigtramp + 51

Thread 1:: com.apple.rosetta.exceptionserver
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd4310c ???
1   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd3c764 ???

Thread 2 Crashed:: com.apple.rosetta.debugserver
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd4a9a0 ???
1   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd4a998 ???

Thread 3:
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd4f87c ???

Thread 4:: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0   ???                                    0x1057489a8 ???
1   ???                                    0x10583a874 ???
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1147d667d mach_msg2_internal + 82
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1147cf71a mach_msg_overwrite + 723
4   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1147c8989 mach_msg + 19
5   CoreFoundation                         0x10ffffac1 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 145
6   CoreFoundation                         0x10fffa380 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
7   CoreFoundation                         0x10fff9a6d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
8   Foundation                             0x11320f13a -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 213
9   Foundation                             0x11320f3b3 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 72
10  UIKitCore                              0x126b11b38 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 364
11  Foundation                             0x1132383c2 __NSThread__start__ + 1009
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x114914259 _pthread_start + 125
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11490fc7b thread_start + 15

Thread 5:
0   ???                                    0x1057489a8 ???
1   ???                                    0x10599edac ???
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x114915a05 _pthread_join + 358
3   ****                               0x10445c1b9 _****_timer_handler_thread + 313 (astb_config.c:1159)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x114914259 _pthread_start + 125
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11490fc7b thread_start + 15

Thread 6:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   ???                                    0x1057489a8 ???
1   ???                                    0x10583a874 ???
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1147d667d mach_msg2_internal + 82
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1147cf71a mach_msg_overwrite + 723
4   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1147c8989 mach_msg + 19
5   CoreFoundation                         0x10ffffac1 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 145
6   CoreFoundation                         0x10fffa380 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
7   CoreFoundation                         0x10fff9a6d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
8   CFNetwork                              0x110aeeeac 0x1108c4000 + 2272940
9   Foundation                             0x1132383c2 __NSThread__start__ + 1009
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x114914259 _pthread_start + 125
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11490fc7b thread_start + 15

Thread 7:: com.apple.coremedia.imagequeue.coreanimation.common
0   ???                                    0x1057489a8 ???
1   ???                                    0x107f21294 ???
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1149147e1 _pthread_cond_wait + 1243
3   CoreMedia                              0x10e5853d6 WaitOnCondition + 11
4   CoreMedia                              0x10e5850e1 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 145
5   MediaToolbox                           0x115e22032 piqca_SharedPollingThread + 191
6   CoreMedia                              0x10e585c5e figThreadMain + 276
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x114914259 _pthread_start + 125
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11490fc7b thread_start + 15

Thread 8:: com.apple.coremedia.videomediaconverter
...
...

Thread 9:: com.apple.coremedia.videomentor
...
...

Thread 10:: com.apple.coremedia.JVTlib
...
...

Thread 11:: com.apple.coremedia.JVTlib
....
...

Thread 12:: com.apple.coremedia.JVTlib
0   ???                                    0x1057489a8 ???
1   ???                                    0x1077ffa14 ???
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x11170143a _dispatch_sema4_wait + 16
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x111701944 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 98
4   H264SW.videocodec                      0x135b268d9 0x13597e000 + 1738969
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x114914259 _pthread_start + 125
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11490fc7b thread_start + 15

Thread 13:
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd3163c ???
1   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd4a1d8 ???


Thread 2 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
```

> The error report says it is crashed by Thread2(com.apple.rosetta.debugserver), but couldn't find much on that.

> Tried with a newly created tvOS app and it ran well. Also, other team members don't have this issue(they are on Macs with Intel Processor).

> From Applications --> Xcode --> Get Info --> **Launch using Rosetta** is unchecked(also tried with checked)

> If I pause the debugger on launch and resume it through every function's flow point of the app, it somehow reaches home page. But, then it freezes, crashes and displays error message:

```
rosetta error: unable to get state for thread the runtime suspended
```

> In Xcode Build Settings and podfile, I have excluded the arm64 tvos simulator sdk

Comment: Did you ever determine the cause of this error?  I've just run into the same error...